# SQL Server smalldatetime issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqldatatypes

I preface this by saying I am NOT a SQL Server database expert, I am a .NET developer.

I am supporting an application that has some rather large tables with many columns and a fair amount of data stored in the tables (not millions of rows, but 10s of thousands). The previous developers decided to use `smalldatetime` all over the place.

We are now running into issues with the max range of this data type being 2079. This is in SQL Server 2012.

My thought is that we need to convert these columns to `datetime2`. Is this the right approach, and if so, what are some of the considerations?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `datetime2` is the most appropriate type for the larger range of temporal values. More precisely, if you don't need fractional seconds, use [`datetime2(0)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#datetime2-description) since it only needs 6 bytes of storage compared to 8 bytes for `datetime2(7)` (the default when no precision is specified).